# Boton borrar fila de tabla mysql en java resultado Jtable

Tags: java, mysql

Bueno tenia un problema y lo termine de solucionar metiéndome a fondo en la acción de seleccionar la tabla. Lo logre espero que les sirva a todo ya que no he encontrado nada en español.

```
    private void botonEliminarClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    int row = tablaResultados.getSelectedRow();//Creo el entero con la seleccion de la fila
    String celda = tablaResultados.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();//Convierto a string el valor
    String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE ID = " + celda;//Creo un String SQL que lo utilizare para borrar en la db.
    int opc = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Deseas eliminar el cliente?", "Pregunta", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);//Dialogo de confirmacion.
    if (opc == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {//Si la opcion es YES(SI) entonces...
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "usuario", "contraseña");//Conexion MySQL
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();//Creo la sentencia SQL
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);//Ejecuto
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente eliminado con exito");//Mensaje exitoso
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hubo un error, intente nuevamente");//Mensaje si hay error.
        }
    }
}
```

Muestro como queda:

[image: Imagen boton borrar cliente]

Estoy abiertos a comentarios que me ayuden a mejorar la seguridad del codigo, o si cometi algun error. Desde ya muchas gracias a todos, especialmente a los usuarios @A. Cedano y @Betto Rodriguez

Comment: No estás convirtiendo correctamente de `String` a `int`. Prueba a ponerlo así: `int Id = Integer.parseInt(m.getValueAt(filsel, 0));`

Comment: La [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) te dice que `getValueAt` devuelve un Object. Debes parsearlo a Integer, no castearlo a int (como te sugieren en el comentario de arriba).

Comment: @A. Cedano muchas gracias, me dice que no puede ser convertido en String cuando pongo lo que me dices, y (m.get lo reemplazo por (tableResultados.getModel ya que ese es el id de mi tabla.

Comment: Intenta de este modo: `int Id = Integer.parseInt(m.getValueAt(filsel, 0).toString());`. Como bien dice @padaleiana, getValueAt() devuelve un objeto, por tanto debes convertirlo a String. Si no funciona así entonces puedes intentar esto: `Integer Id = Integer.parseInt(m.getValueAt(filsel, 0));`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano Ahi actualice el post original porque me sigue dando erro, con el primer codigo que me indicas no me da error al ejecutar el proyecto pero si me da errro al intentar eliminar el usuario, y con el segundo me dice que esta mal el statement.

Comment: En la base de datos la columna de id es **Id** y lo que veo en el codigo es que no creo ninguna conexion a la base de datos, sera que debo agregar un `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "xx", "xx");`???

Comment: Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. Por tanto, si han surgido nuevos errores es mejor que abras una nueva pregunta planteando esos nuevos errores, **después de haber verificado que no es una pregunta repetida**. Es evidente que debe haber sí o sí una conexión válida para ejecutar cualquier consulta de Base de Datos. Pero aquí no se ve el contexto y no es posible saber si la conexión es parte de la clase donde está el método... Por otra parte, tu código tiene varios problemas más, por ejemplo, deberías usar consultas preparadas para evitar peligros de *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 1):

prueba con:

```
String id = String.valueOf(m.getValueAt(m.getSelectedRow(), 0));
```

Y nos comentas como te va.

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error:
_run:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at serviciotecnico.Consultas.botonEliminarClienteActionPerformed(Consultas.java:522)
 at serviciotecnico.Consultas.access$900(Consultas.java:24)
 at serviciotecnico.Consultas$11.actionPerformed(Consultas.java:216)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
_